# Neo4j - Cypher query for finding neighbourhood graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

For the below graph...

[image]

I am struggling to compose a Cypher query that will return me the neighbourhood graph (relationships) of node 1. The neighbourhood graph of 1 includes the nodes connected by the relations I have marked with dotted lines. These are the nodes pointing to 1, pointed at by 1 and all other inter-connections between these nodes.

This below query

```
START a=node(15151) MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) RETURN r
```

gives me back the relations between 1 and 2,3,4,5 but I also need the relations between 2-4 and 3-5 to be returned in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  START a= node(15151) MATCH (a)-[r1]-(b) WITH a,b,collect(b) as bAll,r1 
   MATCH (b)-[r2]->(c) WHERE (c IN bAll) and a <> c return r1,r2
```

Comment: this query is not returning me any results :( but upon further playing around, this query seems to do the job.

START a= node(15151) 
MATCH p1 = (a)-[r1]-(b)
WITH b, r1, p1,a
MATCH (b)-[r2]-(c)
where c in nodes(p1)
return distinct(r2)

Comment: Hey @prav, could you please either select this as the answer, or make a new answer with your query?