# Matching immediate neighbors of a node without returning relationships between neighbors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to return the immediate (outgoing) neighbors of a node, without the relationships between those nodes.  I've tried many, many queries, including these:

```
MATCH (k:Record{name: 'First'})-->(m) 
RETURN k,m
```

and

```
MATCH (:Record{name: 'First'})-[r]->()
RETURN r
```

but I always get all the relationships between the neighbors as well, which is not relevant for my application, and needlessly clutters the visualization.  Is there an easy way to avoid the return of these relationships? I have read a great deal in the last 2 days but have been unable to make this work.

Note: this question
[Neo4j - Cypher query for finding neighbourhood graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471368/neo4j-cypher-query-for-finding-neighbourhood-graph)
seems to imply that either of these should work, because in this question he's asking for exactly what I get: the neighborhood graph.  This makes me think that there's something wrong with my install or the creation of my relationships.

edit: This is a duplicate of 
[is it possible to hide a Node in the neo4j browser once it has been shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634192/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-node-in-the-neo4j-browser-once-it-has-been-shown).  Thanks to Dave Bennett for the answer.

Comment: `MATCH (k:Record{name: 'First'})-->(m) RETURN m`

Comment: i think you likely need to turn off auto-complete in the browser - slider toggle in the lower left hand corner of the borwser

Comment: Yes, Mr Bennett that was it.

Comment: or could mark as a dupe of this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634192/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-node-in-the-neo4j-browser-once-it-has-been-shown?